# Select records (in postgresql with php) between two dates in one column based on input

Tags: php, sql, postgresql

I have problem selecting some dates, here is html and php code:

```
 <div id = "date">

    <form action = "selectdate.php" method = "POST">
        From date: <input type = "date" name = "date" required>
        <input type = "date" name = "referer" style = "display: none" value = "<?=$date?>">
        <br />
        <br />
        To date: <input type = "date" name = "date" required>
        <input type = "date" name = "referer" style = "display: none" value = "<?=$date?>">     
        <input type = "submit" name = "submit" value = "get data">
  <br/>
    </form>
```

and php

```
    $result = pg_exec("SELECT kv.ph, kv.date FROM public.kv WHERE date BETWEEN
 '" . $_POST['date'] . "' AND  '" . $_POST['date']. "' ORDER BY date");
```

Result is only one record, and only shows record from last input date. I want to show records between this two dates.
One more question, why WHERE operator don't work with text columns? I am using php 5.5. Big thanks in advance.

Comment: what if I POST date equal to `now() and now() or false; drop table kv;--`?..`

Comment: Sorry but I am newbie, don't understand.

Comment: your cincatination is prune to sql injection

Comment: @ejovrh2 you should use prepared statements: http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem is in your HTML form you are re-using the `name="date"`.

I'm not sure which field will actually give the value, but one of them will be overwriting the other. so you're essentially saying

`select column from table where date between [date] and [same date]`

Rename your fields to have unique names within the form (e.g. `<input name="date_from"...` `<input name="date_to"...` and use them as `$_POST['date_from']` / `$_POST['date_to']`)

Beyond that, you also really need to look into using paramaterised queries, as it stands your code is incredibly vulnerable to [injection attacks](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/332365/how-does-the-sql-injection-from-the-bobby-tables-xkcd-comic-work).

The PHP Postgres library comes with the handy [pg_query_params function](http://php.net/manual/en/function.pg-query-params.php) to pretty much deal with this for you.